# Replace all array values with a single string

Tags: php, arrays

How can I replace all the values of an array with a single `$string`.

For example I have this :

```
$string = "myString";

$array = array(
   'key1' => 'value1',
   'key2' => 'value2',
   'key3' => 'value3', 
);
```

I want to output this :

```
$replacedArray = array(
   'key1' => 'myString',
   'key2' => 'myString',
   'key3' => 'myString', 
);
```

How can I replace all the values of an array with a `$string`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `array_map()` and return `'myString'`. This will give you a new array.

```
$replacedArray = array_map(function() { return 'myString'; }, $array);
```

If you want to change them in place, you could use a loop or any other function that mutates the original array.

Answer (score 2):

Use an [`array_walk()`](https://www.php.net/array_walk) [*This function modifies your original array itself*]

```
array_walk($array, function(&$v) use($string) { $v = $string;});
$replacedarray = $array; //<--- If you want the results in another array.
```

Go with Alex's answer, If you want the result in another variable.

[Demonstration](https://eval.in/149470)

Comment: Could you use it as a variable instead?

Comment: I don't get you .. sorry ? Did you check the demo ? If you want the results in another variable , check alex's answer. My answer modifies the original array itself.